# if a view controller got unloaded due to low memory pressure, will loadView be called again once it's is about to be shown again?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, loadview

I understand that the viewDidUnload will be called when the app is under low memory pressure, then when the related view/controller is about to be "active" again, will the loadView be called?

Comment: Yes. Place a breakpoint in loadView of your ViewController to see it yourself. You can simulate low memory condition in iOS simulator (Hardware -> Simulate memory warning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will. Check out the [Understanding How Views are Loaded and Unloaded](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW2) section of the iOS View Controller programming guide to see a flow chart of how this works. The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW1) for `-loadView` also notes that this method will be called when the `view` property is accessed, but is currently `nil`.